# Wrong question got flagged, either I made mistake or something wrong happened

Tags: support, flagging

As the title says, I flagged a question as spam but it wasn't the question that is being shown in my profile.

I am not able to find that question anymore but here is what I remember about that question. The asker said it is being asked for password when trying to access his site and upon clicking cancel he can access sites just fine. But upon visiting his both URLs they seemed to be working fine and he seemed to be a spammer trying to get clicks on his site.

So I remember that I flagged that question as spam, but now when I look at my [flag-weight](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/flag-weight/5337) (fortunately found the link in my profile) I see wrong question being listed marked as spam by me.

If this wasn't a bug or something then the only thing I can think of is I was not in my conscious.

Can I take the flag back or is it moderators job to handle it now.

By the way, sorry mods I didn't mean to create a mess for you. :)

Comment: As an update; I have reviewed the underlying data going back to your first vote on May 13th, and there is only one "spam". I also have 1 downvote and one mod-message.

Comment: I think it was this question: ["Whenever I got to my new pages (http://www.cwmags.com/news) it requests login?"](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17668/whenever-i-got-to-my-new-pages-http-www-cwmags-com-news-it-requests-login)

Comment: @Jan Thank, this is exactly the same question. But now it seems they had a legit issue, but as you see the one other user also found that their sites were working fine.

Comment: Did you perhaps flag one of the ***comments*** on the post, not the post itself?

Comment: Sorry for not noticing this earlier, totally forgot about it. yes I think this might have happened or probably I was very sleep or something and flagged the wrong question myself. Sorry for all the trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post you have flagged as spam really does look spammy (needs 10k, as deleted): https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17641/duplicate-categories/17642#17642

If you happen by a link to the one you *thought* you flagged, maybe I can find out more - but I can't see any need to take the existing flag back; that flag looks fine and dandy, dandy and fine.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to find the post. and will update here if found.

Comment: Jan has found the question and has linked in his comment on the question. I hope now the situation will be more clear to you.

Comment: Accepted this is the answer because you mentioned that the question I flagged was fine.

Answer (score 0):

The flags don't seem to logged at any level that community moderator access is sufficient to review. So there is nothing I can help with.

Someone with higher access level might look into this.

Comment: The user's flag-weight link should show this

Comment: @Marc Gravell yep, but question explicitly says that flag that should have been made is not listed there.

Comment: ah, ou said "the flags don't seem to be logged at any level" - that is what I was correcting. I'll dig more, to see what happened.

Comment: @Marc Gravell sorry for confusion, I meant "logging" as in non-public data there